# Help proving this combinatorics identity

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs, set-partition

Suppose $I_{N} := \{1,...,N\}$, $N \ge 1$, is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{P}(I_{N})$ denotes the set of all subsets of $I_{N}$. Suppose we have a family of objects $\{f_{X}\}_{X\in \mathcal{P}(I_{N})}$ and $\{g_{X}\}_{X\in \mathcal{P}(I_{N})}$ such that $f_{\emptyset} = 1$, $g_{\emptyset} = 0$ and:
$$f_{X} = \sum_{\substack{Y \subset X \\ \text{min}X \in Y}}g_{Y}f_{X\setminus Y}$$
with $\text{min}X$ denoting the minimum element of $X$. I want to prove that:
$$f_{X} = \sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\substack{\Pi_{1},...,\Pi_{n}\neq \emptyset \\ \Pi_{1}\cup \cdots \cup \Pi_{n} = X}}\prod_{i=1}^{n}g_{\Pi_{i}}$$
where, in the above we have a sum of partitions of $X$ (thus, the unions are disjoint).

I tried using induction, but got nowhere. Of course, if $|X| =1$, the second formula leads $f_{X} = g_{X}$ which coincides with the first one. However, assuming the formula holds for some $|X'| = k < N$, I could not prove the general formula for $f_{X}$ with $|X| = k+1$ because I don't know how the formulas change when $f_{X'}$ is changed to $f_{X'\cup \{x\}} = f_{X}$. Maybe there is a better way of proving it, which I can't figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Strong induction noticing that $Y\neq \emptyset$ and so $|X\setminus Y|<|X|$. The induction step looks like
$$f_X=\sum _{\substack{Y\subset X\\ \min {X}\in Y}}g_Yf_{X\setminus Y}=g_Xf_{\emptyset}+\sum _{\substack{Y\subset X\\ \min {X}\in Y}}g_Y\sum _{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n!}\sum _{\{\Pi _1,\cdots ,\Pi_n\}\vdash X\setminus Y}\prod _{i=1}^n g_{\Pi _i},$$
exchanging the first two sums, we get
$$f_X=g_Xf_{\emptyset}+\sum _{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n!}\sum _{\substack{Y\subset X\\ \min {X}\in Y}}\sum _{\{\Pi _1,\cdots ,\Pi_n\}\vdash X\setminus Y}g_Y\prod _{i=1}^n g_{\Pi _i}.$$

but consider a partition of $X$ given by $\{\Pi_1,\cdots ,\Pi_n,Y\}$ notice that $Y$ has not an index associated to it, so there are $n+1$ choices for it and so we conclude that we are adding $\frac{1}{n+1}$ of considering all possible choices of indexing for $Y$ and every partition can be founded that way, this gives us $$\sum _{\substack{Y\subset X\\ \min {X}\in Y}}\sum _{\{\Pi _1,\cdots ,\Pi_n\}\vdash X\setminus Y}g_Y\prod _{i=1}^n g_{\Pi _i}=\frac{1}{n+1}\left (\sum _{\{\Pi _1,\cdots ,\Pi_{n+1}\}\vdash X}\prod _{i=1}^{n+1} g_{\Pi _i}\right ).$$ Plugging it in the expression above, we get
$$f_X=g_Xf_{\emptyset}+\sum _{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n!}\frac{1}{n+1}\left (\sum _{\{\Pi _1,\cdots ,\Pi_{n+1}\}\vdash X}\prod _{i=1}^{n+1} g_{\Pi _i}\right )=\underbrace{g_X\cdot 1}_{\text{expr. for }n=1}+\sum _{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n!}\sum _{\{\Pi _1,\cdots ,\Pi_{n}\}\vdash X}\prod _{i=1}^{n} g_{\Pi _i},$$
getting your identity
$$f_X=\sum _{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n!}\sum _{\{\Pi _1,\cdots ,\Pi_{n}\}\vdash X}\prod _{i=1}^{n} g_{\Pi _i}$$

Comment: Phicar, very nice! I am not used to these kind of proofs using combinatorics, so your answer taught me a lot. Thanks and +1!

Comment: @MathMath You are welcome.

Comment: @Phicar: It might be helpful for the reader to plug it in the expression above, shift the index and merge the leftmost term into the sum to precisely get OP's wanted expression. Nice derivation. (+1)

Comment: @epi163sqrt Thanks for your comment, I will improve it as you suggest.